# Mongoose .save() hangs up and doesn't throw error when trying to save an invalid Model (typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

### UPDATE - 14/02/2022

I was actually able to solve the issue.

Problem was, I was importing express-async-errors **before** express, so it wasn't actually catching all the errors from the await/async functions.

By moving **express-async-errors** to the top of the file, the program started to work normally again.

### The Problem

I'm trying to set up an Express Router that saves a Model to MongoDB when a post request is made.

I'm using **express-async-errors** to handle errors, that's why I don't have any try...catch block.

The **Router code** is the following:

```
PortfoliosRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {

  const { user } = request
  const { name } = request.body

  const today = new Date()

  const userToEdit = await User.findById(user.id)
  if (!(user && userToEdit)) {
    return response.status(404).json({ error: 'user not found' })
  }

  const portfolio = new Portfolio({
    name,
    user: user.id,
    dateCreated: today,
  })

  const newPortfolio = await portfolio.save()

  userToEdit.portfolio = newPortfolio.id
  await userToEdit.save()

  return response.json(newPortfolio)
})
```

The **Mongoose Schema and Model** are the following:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { PortfolioDocument, PortfolioModel } from '../interfaces/Portfolio'

const portfolioSchema = new mongoose.Schema<PortfolioDocument, PortfolioModel>({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  stats: {
    currentValue: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    change: String, // to be implemented,
    valueHistory: [Number],
  },
  wallets: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Wallet',
    },
  ],
  trades: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Trade',
    },
  ],
  coins: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'CoinHolding',
    },
  ],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  dateCreated: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date,
    required: true,
  },
})

portfolioSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()

    delete returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject.__v
  },
})

const Portfolio = mongoose.model<PortfolioDocument, PortfolioModel>(
  'Portfolio',
  portfolioSchema
)

export default Portfolio
```

When I try to save a valid Model, it gets correctly saved to the DB, but when I try to push an invalid one (for example, without the name) **mongoose doesn't respond and gets stuck**.

To test it, I'm using **jest** and supertest, the test is:

```
test('if name is not specified 401 is returned', async () => {
    const wrongPortfolio = {
      name: '',
    }

    await api
      .post(baseUrl)
      .set('Authorization', token)
      .send(wrongPortfolio)
      .expect(400)
  })
```

The test just hits the timeOut (that I increased to 30s, quite a lot).

Hope you can give me some insights, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does handling the errors manually make a difference? Eg `catch (err) { res.status(400).send(err) }`